# Spatial regression with misaligned predictor (point) and outcome (point)

Tags: regression, spatial

My outcome (Y) is the type of traffic crash event measured at every intersection (on a street grid). Covariates are measured at the locations of the events.

The predictor of main interest (X, a count) is measured at arbitrary locations on the grid. I wish that it were measured at every intersection, say, but it is not.

I am interested in the effect of X on Y. I need to figure out the best way to incorporate X into a regression model.

I assume that I will find that X is strongly spatially autocorrelated.

Off hand, I can imagine two ways of doing this:

One would be to use some method, like kriging, to guess X at the event locations and then incorporate the estimate, somehow along with its error, into a regression model. However, X is already not measured without error, so it seems like adding error would just result in glop even if there is a relationship. Perhaps there is an implemented method to do this directly.

Any thoughts on this? Thanks.

Comment: I am curious how you would go about kriging an outcome that is a nominal variable ("type of traffic crash event").  Are you perhaps using a geographic generalized linear model in a multinomial logistic form?  Are you sure the *residuals* of your regression will have any spatial correlation?  (Did you check?)

Comment: Hi. Strange that I just this moment came back here after some months only to see a comment you just posted. The point is to predict X (a count) at a point where it is not measured. I have not conducted the analysis yet. Of course it would be a joyful moment for me to find that the residuals were uncorrelated. I doubt that will be the case.

Comment: Anyway, if I did not make it clear, there's no reason to do anything with the outcome variable. The point is to align the predictor with the outcome (not vice versa).

Comment: You seem to be using terms like "outcome" and "predictor" in the opposite of their usual senses.  A *predictor* would be a variable used to guess the value of an *outcome*, which is the quantity you wish to predict.  Regardless of which is which, if the quantity used to predict the response is itself spatially correlated, then the residuals of your regression could very likely exhibit less--and even no--spatial correlation.  Therefore this kind of investigation is almost always worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks  for your thoughts. I'm not mixing anything up. I am asking about a problem with two layers: 

1. A regression to answer the research question about the effect of X on Y (spatial if residuals are autocorrelated).

2. The fact that  X is not measured in the same locations as Y. I could (A) find a way to predict X at unmeasured locations and then use the predicted values in the regression analysis (1), or (B) a more elegant means which combines (A) and (1) into a single operation, or at least takes into account the error of prediction of X in the estimation of the effect of X on Y.